# SPARQL query DBLP

Tags: sparql, rdf

I am running this query

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
?s dc:creator ?name .
?s rdf:type swrc:Article .
FILTER regex(str(?name), "Jeffrey", "D.", "Ullman") .
}
```

and I am getting an error of:

```
Encountered " "," ", "" at line 16, column 41.
Was expecting one of:
    <LANGTAG> ...
    <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ...
    <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
```

What is the matter with that, am I not conforming with the guidelines? I've searched a bit around and I found the same syntax in various posts.

***EDIT:***

when I am asking for

`SELECT *
WHERE
{
?s rdf:type swrc:Article .
?s dc:creator ?name .
}`

I get back:
`s  name
<http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/publications/conf/www/BeszteriV07> [http]  <http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/authors/Istvan_Beszteri> [http]` in a single line where the fist URI is the `?s` and the second the `?name`.

Now I know for a fact that there is an author named "Jeffrey D. Ullman" and I query for:

`SELECT *
WHERE
{
?s rdf:type swrc:Article .
?s dc:creator ?name .
FILTER regex(str(?name), "Jeffrey")
}
LIMIT 10`.

I then get back for example:
`s  name
<http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/publications/conf/www/LimWPVA07> [http]    <http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/authors/Jeffrey_Scott_Vitter> [http]`

So the question here is how will I be able to match "Jeffrey D. Ullman" and see all the Articles he has written.?

Comment: Perhaps Ullman's URI does not have a `dc:creator` property.  You can try `str(<http://dblp.l3s.de/d2r/resource/authors/Jeffrey_D._Ullman>`

Comment: @scotthenninger Yes I investigated your suggestion and indeed I get back results. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex function syntax is incorrect see [SPARQL1.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex).  Note that **regex** takes exactly two or three arguments, the first being the text, the second the pattern, and the final an optional string containing flags.

> #### [17.4.3.14 REGEX](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-regex)
>
> ```
> xsd:boolean  REGEX (string literal text, simple literal pattern) 
> xsd:boolean  REGEX (string literal text, simple literal pattern, simple literal flags)
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Some background research on SPARQL is a very good idea.  Just to point out the exact problem here, regex matches a string against a regular expression.  So the following:

```
FILTER regex(str(?name), "Jeffrey D\\. Ullman") .
```

...will match "Jeffrey D. Ullman".  The following:

```
FILTER regex(str(?name), "Ullman") .
```

...will match "Jeffrey D. Ullman" and anything with "Ullman" in `?name`.  This filter:

```
FILTER regex(str(?name), "Ullman$") .
```

...will match any string ending with "Ullman". And this filter:

```
FILTER regex(str(?name), "^Jeffrey.*Ullman$") .
```

...will match any string starting with "Jeffrey", ending with "Ullman", with any character in between.

And so on...

Comment: **"Jeffrey D. Ullman") ... will match "Jeffrey D. Ullman".**  It will actually match a lot of things, like "Jeffrey DX Ullman", etc., because the `.` is a wildcard in regex.

Comment: Sure.  Fixed in response.

Comment: @chrisis I will edit the question asap so I can show you the full problem I am dealing with. Your answers so far have been most helpful

Comment: ` FILTER regex(str(?name), "Jeffrey D\\. Ullman") .` returns 0 results

Comment: Could depend on how you system escapes the `.`.  Try a single backslash or look up the regex syntax being used.